# Outlook: Pass user name to get AddressEntry

Tags: .net, outlook

In my web application,I need to get a user's freebusy information from exchange server.

I am able to get the required information for my account with the below code and then using the GetFreeBusy method

```js
private void GetCurrentUserInfo()
{
    Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
        Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (addrEntry.Type == "EX")
    {
        Outlook.ExchangeUser currentUser =
            Application.Session.CurrentUser.
            AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Name: "
                + currentUser.Name);
            sb.AppendLine("STMP address: "
                + currentUser.PrimarySmtpAddress);
            sb.AppendLine("Title: "
                + currentUser.JobTitle);
            sb.AppendLine("Department: "
                + currentUser.Department);
            sb.AppendLine("Location: "
                + currentUser.OfficeLocation);
            sb.AppendLine("Business phone: "
                + currentUser.BusinessTelephoneNumber);
            sb.AppendLine("Mobile phone: "
                + currentUser.MobileTelephoneNumber);
            Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to pass a user name from a text box or dropdown list to get the AddressEntry for the user and not sure which method to be used for that. Please help.

Thanks,
Navin

Answer (score 0):

Call `Application.CreateRecipient` passing the name of the recipient, followed by `Recipient.Resolve`. You can then use `Recipient.FreeBusy` or `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy`.

Keep in mind that Outlook cannot be used for ma service, such as IIS.

Answer (score 0):

> In my web application

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. You can read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article.

Consider using EWS instead, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry said, you can `CreateRecipient` then `Resolve` it.

```
                var currentItem = (Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)Globals.RoomAssistantAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
                var oranizer = Globals.RoomAssistantAddIn.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(currentItem.Organizer);
                if (currentItem.Organizer != null && oranizer.Resolve())
                {
                    var user = oranizer.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();
                    ... // do what you want to do
                }
```